# How to create hierarchial parent cildren in recursive data with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make some like threaded data, so the data is showing with tree-view, but there is a problem, the data is not showing correctly, can you give me some suggest?

Here my table

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| division_id | division_parent_id | division_name                    |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | 0                  | division one                     |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 2           | 1                  | division one child one           |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 3           | 1                  | division one child two           |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 4           | 2                  | division grandchild one-one      |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 5           | 2                  | division grandchild one-two      |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 6           | 3                  | division grandchild two-one      |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 7           | 3                  | division grandchild two-two      |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 8           | 4                  | division greatgradchild one-one  |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
| 9           | 4                  | division greatgrandchild one-two |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
```

and my code

```
 function getThreaded($row){

        $result = "<ul>";  
        $result .= "<li>".$row['division_name']."</li>"; 

        $q = $this->db->get_where('tb_m_division', array('division_parent_id' => $row['division_id']));   

        if($q->num_rows() > 0 )
        {  

           foreach($q->result_array() as $row)
            {
                 $result .= $this->getThreaded($row);  
            }


        } 

        $result .="</ul>"; 

        return $result;


    }

    function prepare(){


        $q = $this->db->get_where('tb_m_division', array('division_parent_id' => '0'));  

        foreach($q->result_array() as $row)
        {
           $result = $this->getThreaded($row); 
        }

        // $this->load->view('header');
        // $this->load->view('v_tree', $data);
        // $this->load->view('footer');


        echo $result;


    }
```

the data only displaying the last inputed, if I add the new data then the another data is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function. Something like:

```
function getDivisions($parent_id = 0)
{
    $result = '';
    $this->db->where('division_parent_id', $parent_id);  
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_m_division', 0);  
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $rows = $result_array();

        $result = "<ul>";  

        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
                $result .= "<li>".$row['division_name']."</li>"; 

                // get children
                $result .= $this->getDivision($row['division_id']); 

            $result .= "</ul>";  
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I have not tested that code, so it might be buggy, but the idea is that the function calls itself to get children of each row.

Hope that helps,

Paul

PS If you need to get different classes onto the children just send a level counter through to the function too, so level=1 is top level, level=2 is children, level=3 is grandchildren. Then alter the li line depending on the level set.